# How do I get my Hyper-V set up back?

Tags: hyper-v

How do I get my Hyper-V set up back?

I set up a couple of vitrual machines using Hyper-V.  There seemed to be some memory and resource issues.  So I closed down the virtual machines and Hyper-V and then I ran malwarebytes, ccleaner, and avg to clean up my system.  I uninstalled a few programs that I determined I did not need.  Then I also disabled some programs that run on start up.

There must have been something, within the scope of all of this, that something was done to make Hyper-V behave differently.  And this is why I am posting this. The data in which the virtual machines ran on must still exist on my hard drive and I should be able to load it again.

At this time, when I type to launch hyper-v, I am given the opportunity to launch "Hyper-V Manager". The program loads with no virtual machines listen.  It's title bar says "Console1 - [Console Root]" amd "Console Root is listed as a folder.  How do I set things back to the way they were?  What are your thoughts?  Please help.

[image]

Comment: What options are under File and Action? Please [edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Answer (score 1):

Ccleaner and AVG are dangerous programs. If these two products have an
"undo" option, then use it.

If System Restore is enabled, rollback to before you did all these
manipulations.

Otherwise, I suggest to do a
[Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html)
to try and stabilize the state of Windows.